# Android Studio: Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        FirstFragment ff = new FirstFragment();
        //Fragment fr = new Fragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, ff, "fragment1");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_meets) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_team) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

In the `fragmentTransaction.replace(...)` method, it says wrong 2nd type argument and requires `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` but I'm trying to use the class I made called FirstFragment.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import the supportFragment class in the FirstFragment.java file.
so in that file you would have

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;